# Website doesn't load over HTTPS://www. subdomain

Tags: reactjs, https

The site loads when I go to in any other way. If I go to it in any of these ways www.keystoke.com, keystoke.com, or https://keystoke.com it works just fine. However, when I got to https://www.keystoke.com it doesn't work at all. A lot of eRR_FAILED to load resource errors occur

[Error list in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfpPS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The website's SSL certificate specifies `keystoke.com` as "Certificate Subject", but doesn't specify www.keystoke.com as a "Certificate Subject Alt Name", which you need you you want the certificate to work on both domains.

For example, StackOverflow's certificate has the following alt names:

`DNS Name: *.stackexchange.com
DNS Name: stackoverflow.com
DNS Name: *.stackoverflow.com
DNS Name: stackauth.com
DNS Name: sstatic.net
DNS Name: *.sstatic.net
DNS Name: serverfault.com
DNS Name: *.serverfault.com
DNS Name: superuser.com
DNS Name: *.superuser.com
DNS Name: stackapps.com
DNS Name: openid.stackauth.com
DNS Name: stackexchange.com
DNS Name: *.meta.stackexchange.com
DNS Name: meta.stackexchange.com
DNS Name: mathoverflow.net
DNS Name: *.mathoverflow.net
DNS Name: askubuntu.com
DNS Name: *.askubuntu.com
DNS Name: stacksnippets.net
DNS Name: *.blogoverflow.com
DNS Name: blogoverflow.com
DNS Name: *.meta.stackoverflow.com
DNS Name: *.stackoverflow.email
DNS Name: stackoverflow.email`

Comment: Trying this out. Google Cloud auto assigned the SSL so we missed this part. Once we confirm it works i'll come back and check it off. Thanks!

Comment: This did not work. Do you have any other suggestions?